# Do 親切な (taisetsuna?) really exists?

Tags: words, meaning

From a basic Japanese book I'm reading, I found that word in a vocabulary table. Now I'm having problems finding that word using Google, jisho.org, etc. I can find 大切な (taisetsuna) and that kanji sequence Is what I get if I type the romaji in Windows or Linux, but I don't see the other word as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word in the title of your question is not 大切{たいせつ}, it is 親切{しんせつ}.

If you look 親切 up in jisho.org, you should discover that: [親切 on jisho.org](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%A6%AA%E5%88%87&eng=&dict=edict)

Comment: Then what is wrong is the romaji for the word in the vocabulary table of my book. It says TAISETSU-NA when they should said SHINSETSU-NA. As the meaning of the word 親切 at jisho.org matches the one of the book. Only the romaji differs. How do you put the furigana above your kanji?

Comment: You put it in curly braces after the kanji, like this: {しんせつ}

Comment: @HatoruHansou I assume it's a misprint.  (Even good books probably have one or two mistakes here or there.)

Comment: Now I'm sure it is.